# Remove ./ from output

Tags: linux, bash

I have a code to output data to a txt file but i would like to remove the ./ from the output on each file name

code is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

# fill with more extensions or have it as a cmd line arg
TYPES=( mov mp4 avi mp3 wma)

DIR=$1

# Create a regex of the extensions for the find command
echo "Available Media Files in Directory"

TYPES_RE="\\("${TYPES[1]}
for t in "${TYPES[@]:1:${#TYPES[*]}}"; do
    TYPES_RE="${TYPES_RE}\\|${t}"
done
TYPES_RE="${TYPES_RE}\\)"

# Set the field seperator to newline instead of space
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# Generate output from path and size using: `stat -c "%s" filepath`
OUTPUT=""

for f in `find ${DIR} -type f -regex ".*\.${TYPES_RE}"`; do

OUTPUT=`echo ${f}`";"$OUTPUT

done

# Reset IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS

# Reverse numeric sort the output and replace ; with \n for printing
echo $OUTPUT  | tr ';' '\n' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | sort -nr >playlist.txt
```

Result is:

```
"./You Da One.mp3"
"./Wiz Khalifa Roll Up.mp4"
"./Vybz Kartel neva get a gal.mp3"
"./Tyga Rack City.mp4"
"./Tyga Lap Dance.mp4"
"./Travis Porter Make It Rain.mp4"
"./Travis Porter ft. Tyga Ayy Ladies.mp4"
"./Snoop Dogg feat. Wiz Khalifa Bruno Mars Young Wild & Free.mp4"
"./Shot Caller.mp3"
"./Chris Brown - Your Body.mp4"
"./Chris Brown Turn Up The Music.mp4"
```

Need to remove the ./ from each file

Thanks

Comment: Tried piping it through `| cut -d './' -f 1`?

Comment: `./your_script | sed -e 's/^"\.\//"/'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use basename command to strip the directory filename, in your script probably a good way to use it is in the find command, i.e.

```
  find ${DIR} -type f -regex ".*\.${TYPES_RE}" -exec basename '{}' \;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? Your answer is very vague. Answers on Stackoverflow should generally involve details about how to accomplish a solution, include a reference link, and an example.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo $OUTPUT  | tr ';' '\n' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | sort -nr >playlist.txt
```

to

```
echo $OUTPUT  | tr ';' '\n' | sed 's/^\.\///gi' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | sort -nr >playlist.txt
```